# Is Mirakurun based off any particular anime/manga?

Tags: yuru-yuri

Yuru Yuri has a lot of references to a Magical Girl series that Kyōko does alot of successful dōjin of featuring a girl called Mirakurun who Chinatsu looks like.

I am wondering if Mirakurun is actually based off any particular anime/manga or just a generic reference to the Magical Girl genre.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Majokko Mirakurun is just a parody of the magical girl genre altogether.

There's often jokes where Mirakurun acts very atypically of a magical-girl as presented in the genre:

Mirakurun blasts Rivalrun into the distance with her 10T "Mirakurun Super Hammer". Which is a trope more commonly seen in shonen anime - a high contrast with shoujo works.

[image]

As for gags that may be referencing shows, there's one about the lengthy transformation sequences that we would see in many magical girl shows such as Sailor Moon or Puella Magi Madoka Magica:

[image]
[image]

Mirakurun also says various lines mid battle that are very typical of these type of shows. This one is remarkably similar to sailor moon's phrase:

[image]
[image]

It's possible that the writer was inspired by Sailor Moon or similar series, but the gags are too generic to say for certain, and I'm of the opinion that it's just of the genre in general